# Laravel 5.3 : Many to many realtionship's data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have ,many to many relationship between `User` and `Project`

Realtionship Names are : `User` model have `projects` and `Project` model have `users`. And are correctly formed.

I am using the following code for the data tables :

```
public function handleProjects(Request $request)
    {
        $responseData = \App\Misc::handleDatatable([
            "request" => $request,
            "model" => "\App\Project",
            "actions" => [
            "delete" => function($records) {
                foreach($records as $record) {
                    $record->delete();
                }
                return [
                "status" => "OK",
                "message" => "Successfully deleted the selected product types!",
                ];
            },
            ],
            "columns" => [
            "title" => "title",
            "users.username" => "users.username",
            "level" => "level",
            "users.username" => "users.username",
            "created_at" =>  function($value) {
                return $value->diffForHumans();
            }
            ],
            ]);
        return response()->json($responseData);
    }
```

**Note the `"users.username" => "users.username",` last 8th line, How can i get the username from the `users` table ?**

The relationship names are mentioned above.

And it gives me the following error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.username' in 'field list' (SQL: SELECT projects.*, categories.name AS b74HW, subcategory.name AS rLTng, users.username AS fUfHg from `projects` left join `categories` as `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `projects`.`categories_id` left join `sub_category` as `subcategory` on `subcategory`.`id` = `projects`.`subcategory_id` group by `id` order by `projects`.`id` desc limit 15 offset 0)
```

Comment: Where does this `handleDatatable` function come from?

Comment: @jerodev Its in the controller, Its kinda a bit complex in explaining, Basically it populates the data tables, It works with `OneToMany` realtionships, and also works with `OneToOne` relationships. All i have to do is to get the data from the users table with is liked as `ManyToMany`.

Comment: You are not joining "User" table to your query. So users and also users.username are unknown. Then, without knowing details of *handleDatatable* function, we won't be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty straight. You are not using join on query so it's assuming you have a column called users.username and you have a column username in users table.

How are you calling the relation? Something like:

`$data = Users::find(1)->with('projects')->get();
//this user with id 1, and eager load the relation.`

Also don't forget to loop trough the results like:

`foreach($data->projects as $project) {
...
}`